# Why is this do/while loop stuck in inf. loop?

Tags: java, loops

```
public class Tester
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    Scanner operation = new Scanner(System.in);
    IntegerCalc calc = new IntegerCalc();



    public Tester()
    {

      char choice;
      String value;
      char again;
    }

    public void test()
    {
     char again = operation.next().charAt(0);
        do{
         System.out.println("Please pick one of the following operations: 1. Addition 2. Subtraction" +
          "3. Multiplication 4.Division 5. Modulo 6. Square 7.Square Root");

            int num = operation.nextInt();
        int ch;
        ch = operation.nextInt();


           String choice;
       choice = operation.next();


          switch (ch){
              case 1: calc.addition(num,num);
              break;
              case 2: calc.subtraction(num, num);
              break;
              case 3: calc.multiplication(num, num);
              break;
              case 4: calc.division(num, num);
              break;
              case 5: calc.modulo(num, num);
              break;
              case 6:calc.square(num);
              break;
              case 7: calc.squareRoot(num);
              break;
              default: System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice number.");
            }
              System.out.println("Type x to exit");



        }while(again != 'x' && again != 'X');
      {

      System.out.println("Thank you for using my program!");




    }
```

// The problem with this code is that it does not even prompt the user to input any data either, it seems to just be stuck in a loop and doesn't do anything.  Anyone know what I can do to get this to work?

Comment: Does this even compile? One of your braces near the bottom is facing the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

You have: `char again = operation.next().charAt(0);` outside of the `do/while` loop, so if `again` ever satisfies the `while` condition, you will get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept a character from the user

```
again = operation.next().charAt(0);
```

after this statement

```
System.out.println("Type x to exit");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Type x to exit");
char again = operation.next().charAt(0);
```

This should work